# Split XML File C# - Name Files by Node Value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a way to name split files based on the value of a node.

This code (from an answer by Sergey Berezovskiy) almost does the trick:

```
XDocument.Load(path_to_xml).Root.Elements()
         .Select((e, i) => new { Element = e, File = ++i + ".xml" })
         .ToList().ForEach(x => x.Element.Save(x.File));
```

My XML contains numerous Purchase Orders with first node values like 12345, ideally the split files would be named 12345.xml and so on.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Brian

Comment: What is the specific problem with this code?

Comment: You can read value of first node (12345 in your case) before saving files. And then in save query use `File = ++i + firstNodeValue + ".xml"`. Btw next time please add sample of xml which you have

Comment: Sergey - thanks! This worked perfectly. Next time I'll make sure to add more detail to my question.